# How to make a dapp compatible with browsers like Cipher and Toshi

Tags: dapp-development, dapp-design, browsers

I wish to know how can we make a simple web based dapp compatible to run on browsers like Cipher and Toshi ? Is there any development or testing suite for these browsers that works in Rinkeby Network. I have installed these browsers on my android phone but could not find any options there.

Comment: If you make a DApp, it should be compatible with any web3 client. On desktop, I'd recommend using [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) as the client and then reduce your browser window to mobile size. Are you asking how to make a DApp specifically [mobile-friendly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)? That would be off-topic here.